# concatMap issue in android RXJava

Tags: android, concatmap

Please follow me, I shall tell what I had done so far in my code. 
I called the Observable method to get the 9 function to get the values from DB. Now I need to get an additional data from DB. For this I used concatMap method of RXJava. But I get the following issue. Please check it in the screenshot that I attached.

[image]

Comment: The second parameter of the zip method is of type `boolean` it should of `io.reactivex.Observable` too .. Note :- All parameters of the zip method should return observable type.. `getDataManger().getBuildCoachMarkSeen()` --- `returns boolean`

Comment: It would be helpful if you could write down the code and the issue you are facing. It's difficult to understand from image.